# "NSClassFromString" is invalid in c99

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app worked well yesterday but always failed to build in the new day!I did nothing for code as well as Xcode settings and didn't update anything!But the error "implicit declaration of function 'NSClassFromString' is invalid in c99"displayed when built project.I have checked for some simulate issues in stack overflow but nothing works for me.If someone can help me ?

My code is as following:

```
- (UIView*)indexView {
  Class indexViewClass = NSClassFromString(@"UITableViewIndex");
  NSEnumerator* e = [self.subviews reverseObjectEnumerator];
  for (UIView* child; child = [e nextObject]; ) {
    if ([child isKindOfClass:indexViewClass]) {
      return child;
     }
   }
   return nil;
 }
```

Comment: I think you are making some mistake here.....you at first accepted **arnanta chatterjee's** answer...then unaccepted it and accepted **gnasher729's** answer....but in the comment box of **gnasher729** you have written thank you **arnanta**...Please look into it.....

Comment: @tatan, thanks for your reminder,there is a mistake in my chrome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Implicit declaration invalid" means the compiler doesn't see a prototype for this function. Double-click on the function name and "Show Definition", then make sure you include the right header file.

Much better to use [UITableViewIndex class].

BTW. If you say it compiled yesterday, you haven't changed anything, and it doesn't compile today, then someone else has made a change. Use your source code control system or your Time Machine backup to get a copy of yesterdays state and compare them. Diff tools for that are available for free.

Comment: I'm sorry for last confused comment caused by my chaotic chrome! Never mind!

Answer (score 0):

Class indexViewClass, you have to confirm which type of class you want to assign to indexViewClass , must use a pointer variable.

for example : UIView  *view  =  NSClassFromString(@"LoginView");

Object **view** is an instance of a LoginView class.

Comment: I'm sorry for the first comment to 'gnasher729'!Thank you all the same!